# Get UrlParameters does not work

Tags: php, get, url-parameters

I tried to get 2 url parameters from this url:

http://flying-change.eu/flyingchange/detail.html?id=gXpzX09kyF&stadt=Regensburg&Checkout=true

with the `$_GET` and `$_REQUEST` method like this:

```
$objektid = $_GET['id'];
$stadt = $_GET['stadt'];
```

Now I got the following error:

```
Notice: Undefined index: id in /mnt/webb/a2/87/53907487/htdocs/flyingchange/src/checkout.php on line 10

Notice: Undefined index: stadt in /mnt/webb/a2/87/53907487/htdocs/flyingchange/src/checkout.php on line 11
```

I'm fairly new to php so I would really appreciate some help on this. I can't find the error myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are not actual errors. They are just notices. You're getting these notices because there's no value assigned to them initially. A quick fix to suppress these notices is by using the mute operator. See below:

```
$objektid = @$_GET['id'];
$stadt = @$_GET['stadt'];
```

Comment: I propose using something like that instead: `$stadt = isset($_GET['stadt']) ? $_GET['stadt'] : 'default_stadt';` `@` symbol is so not elegant :).

Comment: Thanks, this worked out ;) I gonna accept this answer in 5 min

Answer (score 0):

Your page has html extension. So there is the mistake, only pages with php extension are analyzed using php... You must rewrite Your URL's to detail.php and change the extension to php. Hope it helps :).

UPDATE:
In that case, you need:

```
/flyingchange/detail.php?id=gXpzX09kyF&stadt=Regensburg&Checkout=true
```

And detail.php:

```
<?php
    $stadt = isset($_GET['stadt']) ? $_GET['stadt'] : 'default_stadt';
    $id = isset($_GET['id']) ? $_GET['id'] : 'default_id';
    print_r($id);
    echo '<br>';
    print_r($stadt);
?>
```

Remember also to be sure that your links are to address on localhost until You are workin on localhost... :)

Comment: I just changed the extension and tried it again, but same error

Comment: Maybe this helps? Which directory is You page root directory? Are You working on localhost?

Comment: Thanks for trying, but I already executed it on server. Hayder Abbass's answer worked out for me.

Comment: Could You write why this isn't working? `@` is not an elegant solution.